# npx create-react-app pulls the following error message

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The following is generated in the command-line when I try to create a React app. what is the possible issue/solution?

````
johnsmith@johnsmith-MacBook-Pro portfolio-projects % npx create-react-app watch-this

Creating a new React app in /Users/johnsmith/Code/portfolio-projects/watch-this.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/johnsmith/.npm/_logs/2022-06-30T16_47_23_299Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting watch-this/ from /Users/johnsmith/Code/portfolio-projects
Done.```
````

Comment: what version of node.js and npm are you using ??

Comment: node- v14.17.3     npm-8.3.2

Comment: reinstall node and npm, It will resolve

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall **node- v14.17.3** and install the [latest version of node](https://nodejs.org/en/) and you'll get rid of this error

Comment: so every time a new version of node comes out I have to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: not necassary you can install the recommanded version 16.15.1 LTS  it will work fine